# Write a custom lookup script for MusicBrainz Picard

Tags: bash, scripts, music, sed, automation

I have a *collection of music files* (~200/batch) that I need to **tag through Picard**. The files have **no metadata**, and **the fingerprinting tool is very inefficient** (<50% mean accuracy).

However, the titles are like this: "**(Song Name)-(Artist).(format)**", and they are almost perfect. I can write a `sed` to extract these.

I need a way to be able to w**rite a custom script that allows me to use the Picard's lookup feature**, with the parameters I extract from `sed` (in-script) from the filename, and do a lookup. Is that possible?

*I am looking for guidelines, but an example would be great.*

As @terdon requested, more details:

- Picard has two modes of identifying a song: 1) Acoustic **Fingerprinting**, and 2) **Lookup** using existing metadata
- For some reason, the first method, ie Acoustic Fingerprinting is giving me very poor result on a certain set of songs
- However, my songs already have the correct Artist Name, Track Title in the filename, I just need to lookup the track to get Year, Cover Image etc.
- The default lookup script (internal to Picard?) is using the complete file name, which has garbage in it to do a lookup, leading to inferior results
- I would like to specify which part of the file name to use for the lookup, as I mention above.

Something like:

```
i="Track Name/ File Name"
$artist="sed -r 's/.../\1/'" $i
$track="sed -r 's/...\2/'" $i
lookup($i, $artist, $track)
```

Of course the scripting language for Picard may be different.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of the `picard` command you would want to run. What is this "lookup feature"? If you make it more explicit, people with knowledge of scripting but no knowledge of `picard` will be able to help.

Comment: @terdon I edited.

Comment: Ah, OK, since you mentioned a script, I assumed you would be launching picard from the command line. AB's answer below should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to use a script, but that's not necessary. Picard has a build-in <kbd>Convert File Names to Tags</kbd> for that and for a better recognition, write the tags to your files taken from your filenames.

Open `picard` and your music folder

[image]

and open <kbd>Tools</kbd> - <kbd>Tags From File Names</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Nailed it. Exactly what I was looking for.